# Inheritance in a Python Car Program

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm working on Inheritance in Python by making a car program, but have came across a problem with the build. Below is my code:

```
class Car():
    """A simple attempt to represent a car"""
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        """Initialize attributes to describe a car."""
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        #setting a default value for an attribute#
        self.odometer_reading = 0

    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        """Return a neatly formatted descriptive name."""
        long_name = str(self.year) + ' ' + self.make + ' ' + self.model
        return long_name.title()

    def read_odometer(self):
        """Print a statement showing the car's mileage."""
        print("This car has " +str(self.odometer_reading) + " miles on it.")

    def update_odometer(self, mileage):
        """Modifying the value through the following method 
           Reject the change if it attempts to roll the odometer back 
        """
        if mileage >= self.odometer_reading:
            self.odometer_reading = mileage
        else:
            print("You can't roll back an odometer!")

    def increment_odometer(self, miles):
        """Incremeting an attributes value through methods"""
        self.odometer_reading += miles

class ElectricCar(Car):
    """Represent aspects of a car, specific to electric vehicles."""
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        """Initialize attributes of the parent class."""
        super().__init__(make, model, year)

my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla', 'model s', 2016)
print(my_tesla.get_descriptive_name())
```

However, I'm getting this error message when trying to run the program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "electric_car.py", line 39, in <module>
    my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla', 'model s', 2016)
  File "electric_car.py", line 37, in __init__
    super().__init__(make, model, year)
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The error seems pretty clear: *"TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)"* You are probably using Python 2.x.

Comment: Ah that was it, seems I need to upgrade to Python 3. Thank you!

Comment: Also, you likely want to extend `Car` from `object`

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.7, when I change your

```
super().__init__(make, model, year)
```

to

```
Car.__init__(self, make, model, year)
```

everything seems to work.  The output is:

> 2016 Tesla Model S